# Describe what's happening with this union

Tags: c, struct, unions

A friend showed me a multiple-choice exercise he had to do in class, and he knows what the right answer is, but he doesn't really understand why or what's happening in the given code.

Here it is (assuming I typed it without any mistake) :

```
What does the following code display ?

typedef union{
  long adr;
  struct{
     unsigned char a,b,c,d,e;
  }x;
}Ip;
static Ip y;
printf("%l2ld | %02X.%02X.%02X.%02X.%02X\n",
       y.adr,y.x.a,y.x.b,y.x.c,y.x.d,y.x.e);
y.adr=1234567890;
printf("%l2ld | %02X.%02X.%02X.%02X.%02X\n",
       y.adr,y.x.a,y.x.b,y.x.c,y.x.d,y.x.e);
y.x.a='A';y.x.b='B';y.x.c='C';y.x.d='D';y.x.e='E';
printf("%l2ld | %02X.%02X.%02X.%02X.%02X\n",
       y.adr,y.x.a,y.x.b,y.x.c,y.x.d,y.x.e);

Answers (?? means a random value) :

A)
         0 | 00.00.00.00.00
1234567890 | 00.00.00.00.00
1234567890 | 41.42.43.44.45

B)
         0 | 00.00.00.00.00
1234567890 | ??.??.??.??.??
?????????? | 41.42.43.44.45

C)
?????????? | ??.??.??.??.??
1234567890 | ??.??.??.??.??
1234567890 | 41.42.43.44.45

D) Something else
```

Now, he has been given the right answer, which is B, but he doesn't understand why and says he would have expected C to be the correct one. Unfortunately I'm not sure either about what happens here. Could someone give us a detailed breakdown of what this code does and help us understand the answer ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: So "your friend" should ask himself.

Comment: This invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Why did `your friend` expect the answer to be `C`?

Comment: None of the above. The `?` values are not random. They depend on the endian-ness of the machine, and the number of bytes in `long`. And you would be better without typos in the format specifiers.

Comment: @Olaf He doesn't have a StackOverflow account, so I wanted to save him the time to create one.

Comment: @A.S.H Because nothing was initialized before the first printf, he expected them to hold random values.

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh I'm sorry, he actually sent me a photo of the exercise and it was easy to confuse "1" and "l" with the font used. I'm assuming it was actually %12ld ?

Comment: I see, but the question is very misleading. If `y` is declared with static scope, then it *is* zero-initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its a misleading question to be honest.  The fact that the variable is declared static is why the initial values are 0.  Static variables are initialized to 0s at runtime.  That eliminates C.

The problem with the answers (and what had me scratching my head for a while) is that the ?'s in B are NOT random numbers.  They are determined completely by what was stored in adr or a-e.  They will just look like gibberish if you dont understand where they are coming from.

In a union, the variables all share the same address space in memory.  In this case adr and struct x share space in memory.  So when you change the value of one it changes the value of the other.

So if you set adr to 1234567890, you are setting the values of a through e as well.  They will be whatever bytes happen to line up to parts of the long that represents adr.

Likewise, if you set a-e it would "corrupt" the value of adr and change what displays.

Comment: They are not well- defined, as there is no information about alignment, padding or the sizes of each type.

Comment: Agreed.  I elected to leave that out for the sake of a slightly shorter answer.  Not well defined, but deterministic.  I just disagree with "random" numbers as a description.  I took that to mean uninitialized (which still isnt random, but closer to it).

Comment: Sorry about this, it's actually more of my bad translation of the exercise (which wasn't written in english). I'm aware that it's not random, but yes, I was talking about uninitialized values.

Comment: Well thats just it, @maxdefolsch.  They ARE initialized at that point since it is a union we are discussing.  What they equal is architecture dependent, but they are not uninited.

Comment: Well on a digital computer it is hard to be truely non-deterministic. However, it is unspecified and that **is** important. Feeling tempted to DV but there is too much correct in your answer.

Comment: "on a digital computer it is hard to be truely non-deterministic"

You're not wrong, but I would argue that when dealing with things like uninitialized memory its impossible to know the facts that would determine the value, so for practical purposes its non-deterministic to the user, which is what counts.  

In this case (given some information about architecture, padding, etc) the values are deterministic to the user.  It would change, however, from one compiler to the next even due to unspecified behavior.

Comment: @BryanShaw: Please read the standard's definitions. The correct phrase is "indeterminate" which itself references "unspecified". It is in general a good idea to have the standard in reach. However, you go into the same direction as I do. That's why I don't understand your first paragragh. Is is just false all variants are "initialised to `0`. This only allies to the first variant, not the second of a union (similar if you use a classical intialiser - i.e. not a designated intialiser).

Comment: However, the actual layout of a `struct` and union is implementation-specific (with some exceptions), so without further information it is not possible to give a final answer (that's why I hate such ambiguous multiple choice questions).

Comment: Well, if its a case of only the first element being initialized then Im just wrong, and will correct my answer.  I have never relied on that aspect of the standard (as far as I know it cost nothing to just set an initial value yourself and its clearer IMO).  Since you seem to know the standard can you point me to the right section to read?  Lets say C11 for the sake of using the same one.  I'd like to read more about it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer could be choice `B`<sup>*</sup>. `y` is `static` qualified, therefore its member (with largest bytes: `adr`)  will be initialized with `0`.

After the assignment `y.adr=1234567890;`, `adr` will be `1234567890`. The values of member of struct members will depend on the bytes in number `1234567890`. Depending upon the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) the output will be different. 
Taking little endian in to account the out put will be
`1234567890` in binary is `1001001 10010110 00000010 11010010`. Hexadecimal equivalent of

```
 01001001 => 49
 10010110 => 96
 00000010 => 02  
 11010010 => D2
```

Similarly for third `printf`, the decimal equivalent of ascii characters

```
'A' => 01000101 
'B' => 01000100 
'C' => 01000011 
'D' => 01000010 
'E' => 01000001
```

In combination `01000101 01000100 01000011 01000010 01000001` is decimal equivalent to `297498001985`.

---

<sub>**Assumptions**: 64-bit machine with little endian hardware.</sub>

Comment: I think its misleading to show what the bytes are and how that translates to hex.  A long in some architectures could be 8 bytes, and then depending on endieness and packing a-d could be 0, even!  Perhaps it would be better to set up an example with a defined architecture, etc, to show what they COULD be for that example?

Comment: Can't disagree with your point, but my answer is on some well known assumptions and the options given in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer is A.

On the first `printf`, `y` has not ben initialized. As it is `static` it is zeo.

On the second `printf` `y.adr` is initialized, but the members not. As they are global, they are zero.

On the third `printf`, everything is initialized. `42` is hex for ASCII `B`.

Comment: Not correct.  There is a union here, so the values of adr and the struct x are overlaid in memory.  Changing one changes the other.

Comment: that's not how unions work. If you set a value in y.adr you also at the same time "set" the values a-e, because they're in the same memory region.

Comment: Stupid me...didn't see the union. Failed my exam :-)